# Business validation rules and microservices

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, authorization, microservices

*Edit* My previous question got edited and it obfuscated the reason for posting the question.

At my company, we use a microservice architecture. The problem I am trying to solve is this:

We have a UI where you can manipulate a calendar and select users from a dropdown list to fill different slots on the calendar. The users that appear in the dropdown to be selected on the calendar must meet certain criteria. Both the data for the user and this criteria (does their company pay for this calendar service or not) both live in the User service.

We have another service specifically for managing the calendar. It stores calendar data, checks for schedule conflcits, etc. The problem that I am facing surrounds API validation. When I select a user from the dropdown in the UI and hit save, I need to send a request to the calendar service to tell it to assign this user to this slot on the calendar. How should the calendar service verify that the user it is being sent meets the criteria to be assigned to a slot?

- Should it call directly the user service via http/gRPC? That would introduce coupling but centralize the logic in the service that owns the data.
- Should I leverage our service bus and use event carried state transfer to make the user and its features available to the calendar service? We have several services like this, and it seems like that would be very inefficient for every service to need a copy of the user table and all of their associated products and features, but that seems to be the path of least coupling.
- Some other option?

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Are you interested in general about the trade-offs between centralized and decentralized authorization models? Or are you specifically looking for answers for your two questions?

Comment: I didn't get it, does the request for creating the event come from the UI? You said UI calls user service to validate the request so why do you need to validate it again in the calendar service?

Answer (score 0):

I would make the calendar to query the user service. It is coupling, but loose coupling as it goes through the API of the user service. If the calendar service queries the database of the user service, that is tight coupling, and that is bad practice.

You can implement the other solution you suggest if you want to improve performance (if there are not too many users).

Answer (score 0):

I think there are three options:

- You can use the SAGA pattern by orchestration or by choreography.
- You can directly call user service in the calendar service.
- You can duplicate required user data in the calendar service via CQRS and integration events.